# Search on Listview is not working on pressing backspace

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented edittext search on listview of object. The search is happening at first time but on press of back space the listview is not getting refreshed. I have similar post and tried to make changes but nothing worked out.

```
 _inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            compadapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

My adapter class

```
public class ComplaintAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private Context context;
List<Complaint> complaints = new ArrayList<>();
String serviceName, ticketNumber, locName, raisedDate, complaintDetails, newDate;
Complaint complaint; //OUT POJO CLASS

public ComplaintAdapter(Context context, List<Complaint> complaints) {
    this.context = context;
    this.complaints = complaints;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return complaints.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return complaints.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    viewHolderItem holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, null, true);

        holder = new viewHolderItem();

        holder.ticketNumberText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticketIdSupervisor);   //TICKET NUMBER
        holder.complaintNameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.complaintNameSupervisor)); //COMPLAINT NAME
        holder.raisedDateText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.raiseDateSupervisor);  //RAISED DATE

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (viewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    complaint = complaints.get(position);

    if (complaint != null) {
        ticketNumber = complaint.getTicketNumber();
        holder.ticketNumberText.setText(ticketNumber);
        holder.ticketNumberText.setTag("ticketNumber");


        complaintDetails = complaint.getComplaintDetails();
        holder.complaintNameText.setText(complaintDetails);
        holder.complaintNameText.setTag("complaint");


        raisedDate = complaint.getRaisedDate();
        newDate = raisedDate.substring(0, 10);
        holder.raisedDateText.setText(newDate);
        holder.raisedDateText.setTag("raisedDate");

        //PASS ALL THE REQUIRED VALUES TO THE COMPLAINT DETAILS CLASS.
        //SO WE CAN DISPLAY ALL THE FIELDS IN THAT ACTIVITY

        serviceName = complaint.getServiceName();  //SERVICE NAME
        locName = complaint.getCallLocationName(); //LOCATION NAME

    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ComplaintDetailsEmployee.class);
            intent.putExtra("COMPLAINT NAME", complaintDetails);
            intent.putExtra("TICKET NUMBER", ticketNumber);
            intent.putExtra("RAISED DATE", newDate);
            intent.putExtra("SERVICE NAME", serviceName);
            intent.putExtra("LOCATION NAME", locName);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public class viewHolderItem {
    TextView ticketNumberText, complaintNameText, raisedDateText;
}

//performs search on a listview of items
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    final Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            complaints = (ArrayList<Complaint>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Complaint> filteredArrList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (complaints == null) {
                complaints = new ArrayList<>(complaints);
            }

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.count = complaints.size();
                results.values = complaints;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < complaints.size(); i++) {
                    String data = complaints.get(i).getComplaintDetails();
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        filteredArrList.add(complaints.get(i));
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredArrList.size();
                results.values = filteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;

}
```

}

Comment: instead of using startsWith, Try using String.contains()

Comment: @Zohair : I replaced with contains but still it does not refreshes.. I think I'm some where updating the original ArrayList and trying to search in it again...

Comment: Yes I think so to! I suggested to use .contains because .contains is good for search functionality as it works like 'IN' query in SQL. Keep a temporary Arraylist to filter data without modifying your original arraylist.

Comment: Also make sure to clear the temp list once filtering is done!

Comment: Ok...Let me give a try...

Comment: @Zohair: I tried adding another araylist but the problem is while setting the adapter in fragment I will have the difficulty..

Sample Code :
 public void getCompliantList(String response) {
        try {
            List<Complaint> complaint = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                complaint.add(Complaint.fromJson(jArray.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
            compadapter = new ComplaintAdapter(getContext(), complaint);
            complaintListView.setAdapter(compadapter);} }

Comment: You can update your adapter's dataset from the filter function and then notify dataset change to the adapter